# Clickable hyperlink on PowerShell's console output

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm having some issues with the following PowerShell script, could you please help me with that?

What I'm trying to accomplish is create a clickable hyperlink in PowerShell's console output. Something like that:

```
$testOutPut = "http://something.com"
Write-Host $OutputConvertedIntoHYPERLINK
```

Where the desired console response would be:

```
clickable link to external app

 http://something.com
```

My goal with it is to show this clickable information on build console into TFS 2015.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that but you can do to open internet explorer, with a specific URL:

```
$InternetExplorer=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$InternetExplorer.navigate2("http://stackoverflow.com")
$InternetExplorer.visible=$true
```

Comment: Is this possible with better browsers?

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes it is. To use the default browser use "start www.google.com".

Answer (score 3):

Clickable links, when referring to the PowerShell console window, are not supported **by itself.**  While the PowerShell console can catch mouse clicks and such, interaction within the console (with the text output it displays) isn't capable of handling hypertext references like you want directly.

An alternative, since this is not feasible, would be to write to an HTML file, then launch said HTML file in a browser.  Another consideration: implement something like PrimalForms, that adds the functionality of Windows-style designs to provide the clickable link for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already saw these options but they aren't useful to my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you should ask a new question, describing what you are trying to accomplish.  What you are asking to do isn't possible, in the way you described.

Answer (score 3):

you can open chrome or FF to a specific page by using a start-process command

```
Start-Process "chrome.exe" "https://www.google.com"
```

So you could build on that and do something like this in the console:

```
Do {
    Write-Host "Open Google?" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $result = Read-Host "   ( y / n ) " 
}Until ($result -eq "y" -or $result -eq "n")
if($result -eq "y"){
    Start-Process "chrome.exe" "https://www.google.com"
}
```