# Powershell script to convert text to URL

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I have this script that is supposed to convert the Text to URL (http://www.ObjectSharp.com) But its not working.

Script:

```
$TempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$fullurl = "http://www.ObjectSharp.com" | set-content $Tempfile
Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=ObjectSharp;]$Tempfile"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `convert to url'?

Comment: This is azure devops build summary page. URL is coming like text via above script i want it as URL so if i click on it it have to open in next window of browser.

Comment: Please add the information in your comment to the question. See: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ErAbhijitKupale - so ... you want the text to be recognized by the azure console as a clickable item? please, add that to your Question. [*grin*]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickable hyperlink on PowerShell's console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293078/clickable-hyperlink-on-powershells-console-output)

Comment: @iRon its not working $TempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$fullurl = "http://www.ObjectSharp.com" | set-content $Tempfile
Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=ObjectSharp;$OutputConvertedIntoHYPERLINK;]$Tempfile"

Comment: It isn't exactly clear where you want to place the link, maybe this q&a helps: [TFS write string message to build summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57768225/1701026)

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2013/07/how-to-create-a-clickable-link-in-powershell.html#comments

Comment: Is your output environment in `html` or `powershell tools` ?